# How to use HdmiControlService

Tags: java, android, android-service, android-context, hdmi

I'm trying develop an app that can turn on/off the TV through HDMI-CEC. I found that android source project had a service call `HdmiControlService` [here](https://source.android.com/devices/tv/HDMI-CEC.html). But I don't have any ideal about how to using this.

I know `HdmiControlService` is available for android 5.0, so I change the sdk version to 21, But it's still telling me that `can't not resolve symbol HdmiControlService`.

Does any one have any ideal about how to use this api or any code for me.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 10):

From [`Context.java`](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/content/Context.java#L3454) class:

```
    /**
     * Use with {@link #getSystemService} to retrieve a
     * {@link android.hardware.hdmi.HdmiControlManager} for controlling and managing
     * HDMI-CEC protocol.
     *
     * @see #getSystemService
     * @see android.hardware.hdmi.HdmiControlManager
     * @hide
     */
    @SystemApi
    public static final String HDMI_CONTROL_SERVICE = "hdmi_control";
```

You can see it is annotated with both `@SystemApi` and `@hide`, which means that it is not available for public API. It is [*"exposed for use by bundled system applications"*](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/annotation/SystemApi.java#L31) only.

Thus, there is no way to use that service (yet).

Comment: Hummm.. so if I really want use this API, I have to remove the annotation and rebuild the android system?

Comment: I do not have experience in that, but it seems to me that you have a rightful point.

Comment: @azizbekian Are you aware of any other way for an app to perform HDMI-CEC commands?

Comment: @fiddler, no, sorry. Cannot find something closer than this after investigating sources.

Comment: why is it hidden? to prevent malicious apps messing with your tv?